# Containers reallocation monitoring

Tags: c++

Is there a way to monitor containers (`std::vector`, `std::map`, etc.) that changes size (reallocate memory) during runtime? It seems to me that maybe with valgrind I could indicate specific containers, but I don't know how.

Comment: There's nothing in the C++ library that works this way. There's nothing in valgrind that works this way. The closest to this I can think of is to use `gdb` and set a watch breakpoint on the vector's innards. All that it will give you is a breakpoint every time the vector reallocates. This does not seem to be very useful.

Comment: Use a custom allocator.

Answer (score 6):

You can write an allocator that monitors the (de)allocation and (de)construction that it does.

E.g. assuming some `monitor_` functions

```
template <typename T>
struct monitoring_allocator : std::allocator<T> {
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr T* allocate( std::size_t n ) { 
        auto p = std::allocator<T>::allocate(n); 
        monitor_allocate(p, n); 
        return p; 
    }
    constexpr void deallocate( T* p, std::size_t n ) { 
        monitor_deallocate(p, n); 
        std::allocator<T>::deallocate(p, n); 
    }
    template< class U, class... Args >
    void construct( U* p, Args&&... args ) { 
        std::construct_at<T>(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
        monitor_construct(p); 
    }
    template< class U >
    void destroy( U* p ) {
        monitor_destroy(p);
        std::destroy_at(p);
    }
};
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I think it'll lack some `typedef`s if done like this. I suggest inheriting from `std::allocator<T>` instead. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/radv9Go95)